# Google form validate if submitted value matches list

Tags: regex, forms, validation, string-matching

**My two questions are**:

- Can I check if a submitted value matches entries in a list of accepted answers with Google Forms?
- What kind of solution would you recommend?

**Explanation of my goal**:

I would like visitors to go on to the second page ONLY if their first answer matches one of the expected answers from a predefined list. (email list for example, or identification name)

Only those who would fill in the field with an expected email address would go on to the second page.
Unwanted visitors would then be given an error message.

I was thinking of the regexp solution at first, but there is probably a much easier and better solution.

Thank you for your time and clues.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve my problem, so here's is the solution for those who will try and do something similar.

Answer found here:
[Google Forms : REGEX](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/postini/docs/admin/en/admin_ee_cu/cm_regex.html)

So it's answer type SHORT ANSWER
-> advanced settings
REGEX -> MATCHES -> mail2@mail1.com|mail2@mail2.com|mail3@mail3.com

For a limited list of email addresses, this wors just fine :)

P.S.: Thank you James anyway!! I appreciated even your interest in this question, so thank you.